# how can i save marker throught the application life?

Tags: android, dictionary

Can any one tell me how can i save a marker in my application by clicking a button. When i add marker like this:

```
protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Map.addmarker(new markeroptions().text("xxx").dragabble(true).position(new latlng(xx,yy)));
}
```

it actually saves the marker even if i restart my application but when i do so:

```
protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{  
    Map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            //clicking on map long to create a marker       
            //adding the marker

            Map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLatLng(xxx,yyy)).draggable(true).title("hello new marker"));                  
        }
    });
}
```

it adds the marker but it is not seen after my program is restarted. How can the marker be saved by clicking the map or button?